# How to write a bann function in php?

Tags: php

I have an array of many banned string and i have a small string contains one keywords, too and i want to write a function in php like this:

```
function is_ban($keyword,$bannedList) {
}
```

where `$keyword` is small string and `$bannedList` is an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => php
    [1] => html
    [2] => java
    [3] => css

    [....]


)
```

The function check keyword in banned list and return true or false.

Comment: Do you want that if the keyword is php than search in the array and than tell if it matches or not

Comment: the function your looking for is `in_array`

Comment: Do you want this `is_ban(1, ['1foo'])` to also return true?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, I Want it , too

Comment: That's a [clbuttic](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html) mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function is_ban($keyword,$bannedList) {
  return in_array($keyword, $bannedList);
}
```

Comment: `in_array` does already return a boolean value, you don't need to wrap it into another function.

Comment: Fixed that for you ;-)

Comment: So, this gets down voted because it's exactly the same as another answer that was posted *later*? That makes sense =p

Answer (score 3):

This is my first reply on a php related question. As others have said, if you have a precisely defined array of banned words, and you have already taken the time to get the word $keyword from the user, then by all means just use PHP's native function in_array().  You may however need to do the following:

```
if(in_array(strtolower($keyword), $bannedList)){ //return true }
```

Just make sure of course that your $bannedList array is all lowercase as well.  If however you need to do pattern matches inside longer strings, then you'll need to resort to regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to define your function

```
function is_ban($keyword,$bannedList) 
{
    return in_array($keyword, $bannedList);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to wrap `in_array` into another function?

Comment: because the OP question is about creating a function

Comment: If you're happy and you know it Parse error: syntax error

Comment: @PeeHaa, I forgot `;`, I updated the post, thank you

Comment: @moonwave99 because I LOVE wrapping existing functions in my own lovely functions :))

Comment: @moonwave99 it allows you to make tweaks to `is_ban()` later without having to selectively replace calls to `in_array()`.

Comment: `is_ban` is more meaningful than `in_array`